# Problems with ddply for splitting a large number of categories in R

Tags: r, transform, plyr, large-data

I recently asked a question about counting the number of times an element had repeated itself (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669553/how-to-assign-number-of-repeats-to-dataframe-based-on-elements-of-an-identifying/7669607#7669607) in a large data-frame. I received some very helpful advice, which worked on a small number of rows, but now need to perform the operation on a much larger level (over 255k rows, with around 100k "groups" being formed using ddply):

```
system.time( data <- ddply(data, "uid", function(x) {x$time <- 1:nrow(x); x}) ) #uid is the grouping variable, for which I need to count the number of repeats for output like

uid    time
ny1    1
ny1    2
ny2    1
ny2    2
ny2    3
```

Trying to perform this operation on the larger data set results in R choking due to memory issues. Are there any obvious solutions to this? Thanks in advance (especially for patience as I'm a new "programmer").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a new answer to your original question here [How to assign number of repeats to dataframe based on elements of an identifying vector in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669553/how-to-assign-number-of-repeats-to-dataframe-based-on-elements-of-an-identifying/7734905#7734905).

That will hopefully help you there and here.

Comment: This second solution worked for the particular problem I was facing; I will play around with data.table and get back to you as I suspect this type of thing will arise again in a different application. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For truly large problems like this, you might try using `data.table`s rather than `plyr`:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(data)

data[,transform(.SD,time = NROW(.SD)), by = uid]
```

assuming the `time` column doesn't already exist.

I'm still in the process of learning `data.table`, so as I tinker with this it appears this may be simpler (and maybe faster):

```
data[,rep(.N, .N),by = uid]
```

`.N` appears to an internal variable that represents the number of rows of each subgroup.

Comment: I'd be interested in this being run against my solution with system.time() around it. I too what to need to learn/work more with data.table, I doubt it offers any benefits for only 255k rows unless there are a heap of columns...